# Create multiplanel plot for multiple datasets in apply loop

Tags: r, plot, lapply

Aloha! I am new to R and presently going through a steep learning curve. I apologize if I get all the R language wrong.

I have many datasets, each with 6 columns of numeric data. So:

- df1: columns 1 thru 6
- df2: columns 1 thru 6
- df3: columns 1 thru 6   ...and so forth

I am able to create a multipanel plot in one PDF outside of an `lapply()` loop using the following code:

```
pdf(file="plot1.pdf, width=8.5, height=11)
par(mfrow=c(3,3), oma=c(1,1,8,1))
plot(a ~ b, df1)
plot(a ~ b, df2)
plot(a ~ b, df3)
...
dev.off()
```

Since I have so many datasets that I want to plot from and display in the same PDF, I tried using a `lapply()` loop so I can loop through the datasets. In the following example, let's say I have 9 datasets so I can create a one page multiplot of 3 rows by 3 columns.

```
Test <- lapply(1:length(files), function(x) {     # files = list of 9 file names
  a <- as.data.table(read.csv(files[x], header = TRUE))
  pdf(file="plot1.pdf, width=8.5, height=11)
  par(mfrow=c(3,3), oma=c(1,1,8,1))
  plot(col 1 ~ col 2, a)
  dev.off()
})
```

When I ran this code, I get one PDF with only one plot. That plot belongs to the last dataset in the list of files. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to move the device opening (`pdf()`), configuration (`par()`) and closing (`dev.off()`) outside of the loop. Also, you can loop over the files directly, and there is no need to create a data.table. Also fixed your formula syntax.

```
pdf(file="plot1.pdf", width=8.5, height=11)
par(mfrow=c(3,3), oma=c(1,1,8,1))
Test <- lapply(files, function(x) {
  a <- read.csv(x, header = TRUE)
  plot(col1 ~ col2, a)
})
dev.off()
```